# org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I'm trying to access another server for uploading files with Java. I'm able to connect to the server but I'm unable to upload the file.
The server (**Spring Boot** application) accepts the file in this way.

```
@PostMapping(value = ("multipart-store"), headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"))
CustomResponse gridFs(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception {
    return new CustomResponse(storageService.storeObject(multipartFile));
}
```

I had tried couple of ways to access the server.
My Java code to access the server is below.
1st way

```
try {
  final File uploadFile2 = new File("/home/thrymr/Desktop/invoicesample.pdf");

  final String requestURL = "http://localhost:8082/data/multipart-store";

  final MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);

  multipart.addFilePart("file", uploadFile2);

  final List<String> response = multipart.finish();

  System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

  for (final String line : response) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
} catch (final IOException ex) {
  System.err.println(ex);
}
```

```
public class MultipartUtility {

  private final String boundary;
  private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
  private final HttpURLConnection httpConn;
  private final String charset;
  private final OutputStream outputStream;
  private final PrintWriter writer;

  public MultipartUtility(final String requestURL, final String charset) throws IOException {
    this.charset = charset;

    this.boundary = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "";

    final URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    this.httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    this.httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    this.httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
    this.httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    this.httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + this.boundary);
    this.outputStream = this.httpConn.getOutputStream();
    this.writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.outputStream, charset), true);
  }

  public void addFilePart(final String fieldName, final File uploadFile) throws IOException {
    final String fileName = uploadFile.getName();

    this.writer.append("file : "+uploadFile);
    this.writer.flush();

    final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      this.outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    this.outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    this.writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    this.writer.flush();
  }

  public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
    final List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

    this.writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
    this.writer.append("--" + this.boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
    this.writer.close();

    final int status = this.httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.httpConn.getInputStream()));
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.add(line);
      }
      reader.close();
      this.httpConn.disconnect();
    } else {
      throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }

    return response;
  }
}
```

2nd way

```
final File file = new File("/home/thrymr/Desktop/invoicesample.pdf");  
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8082/data/multipart-store");  
final FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);  
final MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();  

builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
builder.addPart("file", fileBody);  

final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();  
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=gv");  
final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();  
post.setEntity(entity);  

final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: You commented out all the code that write the part header, so why do you think that would still generate a valid multi-part request?

Comment: I had commented the code for "addHeaderField()", but not for "addFilePart()". I just wanted to know whether the code written in addFilePart() is correct or not.

Comment: I was talking about the code *in* `addFilePart()`, the commented code you've now removed. If you never write a start-boundary line, and the associated part headers, there will be no parts in the content, and that is why server complains that `file` part is missing. You didn't create valid `multipart/*` content. So no, the code written in `addFilePart()` is *not* correct.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, now i had solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above addFilePart() method, by replacing `this.writer.append("file : "+uploadFile);` with below lines of code, i'm able to solve the issue.

```
this.writer.append("--" + this.boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
this.writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
.append(LINE_FEED);
this.writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(LINE_FEED);
this.writer.append(LINE_FEED);
```